# Snow Leopard server SVN problem

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, osx-snow-leopard

We have an Snow Leopard Server that we do development on (web related stuff - Apache, mySQL, an recently we started using Subversion as well).

The working stations are Macs as well and we develop in Coda. However, recently something must have happened with the server, because from Coda I cannot se repository related information, I cannot update or submit any new version of my work to the repository.

Also, there is an error that Coda gives once in a while (when it tries to connect to the repository I assume): `svn: The VCC property was not found on the resource`.

The problem is, that as far as I can tell, nothing changed in our setup from the moment it was working, and I cannot figure it out what the problem is, in order to solve it.

Thanks in advance for your answer,
Constantin TOVISI

Comment: What happens when you try to load the SVN path/URL in a browser? Also, do you get any errors in the apache logs (assuming you've got `dav_module`, `dav_fs_module`, `dav_svn_module`, and `authz_svn_module` enabled)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there was a problem with one of the Apache .conf files.

There is a great step by step tutorial here that helps a lot with setting up SVN on a Leopard Server: http://developer.apple.com/mac/articles/server/subversionwithxcode3.html

Thanks to all the ones that tried to help out with this,
Constantin TOVISI